# Load webpage with modified css?

Tags: css

An odd query really but wandered if anyone knew of a way to link a website to another site with custom css. For example if there is a site you visit regularly on a mobile phone, navigate to your own web address so it loads a different web page with your css e.g. you want google to show in a different way you go to http://m.mywebaddress.com/google and it loads google, but with my own custom css.
I know you can do it using Chrome developer tools, but that only helps if you view the site from your own chrome. I may be craving the impossible here but thought i would ask all the same!

Comment: There are probably several approaches you can take to achieve this.

One, would be to fetch the target URL on your webserver, and inject your own CSS into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of a browser extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

You could do the following:

1. Scrape the desired page using your preferred environment scraping
   package:
   [Options for HTML scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping)
2. Load the scraped HTML onto your own page.
3. Style your page using your
   own CSS.

This is somewhat limited though, as you're only scraping the HTML markup, and not including any JavaScript hooks from the original site.