# How to load a page with a custom css without browser extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is similar to 
[Load webpage with modified css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693568/load-webpage-with-modified-css)
but with a few more limitations.

I'm trying to direct to one of links from my company and I have no server access to it. But my supervisor wants me to use that page and just add the css to it. I've researched around and only found two solution-ish methods. One is to fetch the page and just copy it (which is just simply making my own page). Or install a browser plugin that lets me modify it, but that only changes the website on my browser.

So is it possible to create a link that directs to a specific website and automatically mods the css with javascript?

I mean I'm not affecting the website itself. It just changes the appearance for anyone who goes through my link

Comment: Not without cooperation from the website.  You're asking for a security hole.

Comment: I see. Yeah I kind of realize that while I was researching about it. But I just wanted to ask and make sure. Thanks

Comment: You could make and provide a bookmarklet that would do this for you? It's not a browser extension, after all. http://juicystudio.com/article/accessible-stylesheet-bookmarklet.php

Comment: Oh I thought a bookmarklet was a type of browser extension so I didn't look into it any further. I'll do that now and see if I can use it. Thanks!